# Routing based on different environments with React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-router-v4

I have developed a react redux application using create-react-app . Now i want to deploy it in different environments like my local , i.e localhost/abc , some UAT i.e https://10.123.123/abc etc , and Production i.e https://someUrl/abc . How to make a base URL with different environment configurations like local, UAT , Prod etc.

Comment: create-react-app allows you to create env variables, check out its docs

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score -1):

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "sh -ac '. .env.${REACT_APP_ENV}; react-scripts build'",
  "build:staging": "REACT_APP_ENV=staging npm run build",
  "build:production": "REACT_APP_ENV=production npm run build",
  ...
}

$ npm run build:staging
```

Check this out!

https://medium.com/@tacomanator/environments-with-create-react-app-7b645312c09d